# Why I can't download and use OGB (Open Graph Benchmark)?

Tags: python, import, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

update: This code can just cause the perpetual running. Even if I don't  add any other code ?

```
from ogb.nodeproppred import PygNodePropPredDataset
```

---

Here is my code, and I want to download the OGB.

```
import torch_geometric.transforms as T
from ogb.nodeproppred import PygNodePropPredDataset


dataset_name = 'ogbn-arxiv'

dataset = PygNodePropPredDataset(name=dataset_name,
                                 transform=T.ToSparseTensor())
print('The {} dataset has {} graph'.format(dataset_name, len(dataset)))

# Extract the graph
data = dataset[0]
print(data)
```

But when I run this code, it just keep the state of running and output nothing.

I think I've already match the requirement which shows in OGB website.

I use windows11 and pycharm.

Comment: Please post the code as text but no an image.

Comment: I just fixed the images and added some new finding . I'm so confused with it :)

Comment: Edit your post. You will see something like this [![enter image description here][x]][x] and scroll to bottom you will see something like this [x]: https://i.stack.imgurxx.xx.xx.pg. then delete it.

Comment: ok, now I delete all the images, thanks for telling me that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the OGB dataset, you should uninstall the "outdated" package, as it seems there are some conflicts among the package. For more details, please read the [OGB github issues](https://github.com/snap-stanford/ogb/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue, putting the `from ogb.nodeproppred import PygNodePropPredDataset` on top solved this problem. So, first import `PygNodePropPredDataset` and then other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same question. Just import PygNodePropPredDataset and program keeps running. But it outputs nothing. I delete the whole environment used in this program and recreate one which just pip python, PyG and ogb. Then it works.